# useAuth custom hook setting isAuthenticated to false even when user is authenticared

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I've coded the following useAuth hook in order to check if user is authorized to see certain components. I restrict them with a HOC. But event getting the user from the backend and entering the true condition in the if statement (where console.log states that the user is authenticated), isAuthenticated is received false. What am I missing here

PrivateRoutes.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { useAuth } from './Auth';

import { Outlet, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom'

const PrivateRoutes = () => {
    const { isAuthenticated } = useAuth();
    return(
        isAuthenticated ? <Outlet/> : <Navigate to="/login"/>
    )
}

export default PrivateRoutes
```

Auth.tsx

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:8000',
});

export const useAuth = () => {
    const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);


    const getUser = async () => {
        const response = await instance.get('/user', { withCredentials: true });

        if (typeof response.data.user === 'object' && response.data.user !== null) {
            console.log("authenticated")
            setIsAuthenticated(true);
        } else {
            console.log("not authenticated")
            setIsAuthenticated(false);
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        getUser();
    }, []);

    console.log(isAuthenticated)
    return { isAuthenticated };
};
```

Comment: The initial state is false, which will always cause a navigation to the login page.

Comment: The initial `isAuthenticated` state matches the unauthenticated state, so the redirection to log in occurs. The private route component should wait for the authentication check to complete prior to making a decision to redirect or render the protected content via the outlet.